# How to implement CordovaWebView in an activity

Tags: android, cordova

I try to implement CordovaWebView  in an activity but I get the following Error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class
org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
```

Here is my Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" /-->

<org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView
    android:id="@+id/tutorialView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and:

```
public class NewActivity extends Activity implements CordovaInterface {

CordovaWebView cwv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    cwv = (CordovaWebView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialView);
    cwv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
}
```

My Phonegap version is 2.2.0
can anyone tell why it is happening?

thanks in advance

kobi

Comment: Did you look at Joe's example? https://github.com/infil00p/CordovaActionView

Comment: Also, there should be a *lot* more to that stack trace than just one line.

Comment: Is this possible to get the CordovaWebview without xml layout.? i.e. CordovaWebview webview = new CordovaWebview(this); webview.loadurl("some url");

Answer (score 2):

try add this in your main activity class-

```
public Activity getActivity() {
      return this;
    }
```

ref: http://3z.uipc.org/blog_wp/mixing-phonegap-webview-with-native-ui/

Comment: above link is not working, dont use the link which will disappear in future