# Cordova 3.1 unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: cordova, android-webview

I've been trying to ugprade from Cordova 3.0 to 3.1, but when using custom embedded webviews I keep getting the following error.

10-11 13:28:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32129): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 13:28:11.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32129): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.TestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_webview.md.html#Android%20WebViews

I followed this tutorial and it works for 3.0, but I can't get it working for 3.1. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[How to implement CordovaWebView in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364650/how-to-implement-cordovawebview-in-an-activity)

There is it bro... I had the same error and this helped me.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, please consider adding the essential points here also. Doing so would make sure that your answer remains valid even if the link becomes inactive.